# How to access the raspbian via Wifi

Tags: pi-3

My Raspberry pi 3 is connected on Wifi. My purpose is to access the raspbian via wifi to be able to edit the code. My attempt to access with the Ethernet is successful, however when I try to do the same via Wifi it seems to not work.

Link already tested but without luck:
https://github.com/OpenLabTools/OpenLabTools/wiki/SSH-on-Raspberry-Pi-with-Ethernet-and-or-WiFi

Any suggestion ?

Comment: what command are you using to connect to the wifi? What is the IP of the WiFi connection on the Pi?

Comment: I only connected the Pi3 to the monitor and then tried to connect it to the wifi. At this point, the connection to the wifi always fails (tried with different wifi networks).

Comment: It would help if you shared what type of error you are getting. Sounds like you're not using the correct passphrase for the wireless network. It's pretty straight forward in the GUI.

Comment: It would also help to know exactly how you tried to connect to the WiFi, and what protocol you are using. No SSH connection via WiFI will work until you can connect. So your issue is not with SSH not working but with the WiFi config. Please also edit your question and add the output of the ifconfig command.

Comment: I think I was mistaken; I read this as the OP can't connect to wifi, not connect to the Pi *over* wifi

Comment: Following a 4 year old tutorial for an obsolete OS won't help. List **EXACTLY** what **YOU** did

Comment: do you know the raspberry pi's wifi IP address?

Answer (score 0):

SSH
1) Enabled ssh link by console:
$sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
In #Authentication Section
   Edit PermitRootLogin yes

Restart SSH
$sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart OR

$sudo service ssh restart

2)By Raspi-config

3)Configuration on startx (Graphics Mode)

ENABLED WIRELESS
Edit /etc/dhcpcd.conf for static address
and /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf

In last line:
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.110/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8

interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.10/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

network={
   ssid="your_ssid"
   psk="your_ssid_password"
}